# Как вписать пробел в значение атрибута

Tags: html, angularjs

Здравствуйте, я пишу директиву на angularJS, для удаления некоторых подстрок в строке, в основном нужно удалять пробел, сама директива выглядит примерно так

```
<div remove-substrings=" "></div>
```

и вот в кавычки мне нужно подставить пробел &nbsp не помогает (приходит просто пустая строка), ="' '" тоже не помогает, регулярку написать, типо ="/ /g" тоже не выходит, она оборачивается и превращается в строку. Как же решить эту задачу?

Comment: Покажите код самой директивы `removeSubstrings`.

Answer (score 0):

По умолчанию удаляет пробелы в начале и в конце строк.

```
<div remove-substrings=" " data-ng-trim="false"></div>
```

https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/docs/api/ng.directive:input.text

Comment: Строка может быть кописастнута и в ней могут быть пробелы в середине

Comment: В чем у вас вообще проблема? В том что не можете передать пробел в качестве аргумента в директиву или некая другая?

Comment: Да, именно это, я не могу передать пробел в качестве аргумента

Comment: Вы попробовали ng-trim выключить?

Comment: Да, попробовал, как вы указали в ответе